# How not to repeat myself with duplicate tests in mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

here's my test.js file, I'm trying to put some tests in the `duplicateTests` function and use this function in different test files:

```
function duplicateTests(user) {
    it('nested test 2', done => {
        console.log('user in duplicateTests function: ', user)

        if (user) {
            done()
        } else {
            done(new Error('Dummy error'))
        }
    })
}

describe('users', () => {
    let user

    before(async () => {
        user = await models.User.create({
            name: 'john',
        })
    })

    describe('TEST THE BEFORE HOOK', () => {
        it('test 1', done => {
            console.log('user: ', user)

            if(user) {
                done()
            } else {
                done(new Error('Dummy error'))
            }
        })

        duplicateTests(user)
    })
})
```

the log inside 'test 1' logs the user correctly:
`user: { name: 'john' }`

but the log inside 'nested test 2'  logs this:
`user in duplicateTests function: undefiend`

so `user` is `undefined` in the nested test and the nested test fails as you could predict.

I tried returning a promise inside my 'before' hook but that didn't solve the problem.
Thanks for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `duplicateTests()` runs before `before()` has finished.

```
describe('users', async () => {
    let user

    user = await models.User.create({
        name: 'john',
    })

    describe('TEST THE BEFORE HOOK', () => {
        it('test 1', done => {
            console.log('user: ', user)

            if(user) {
                done()
            } else {
                done(new Error('Dummy error'))
            }
        })

        duplicateTests(user)
    })
})
```

Or you can exploit javascript's object reference:

```
function duplicateTests(context) {
    // let user = context.user doesnt work here
    // because before() has not run yet.

    it('nested test 2', done => {
        // reference is collapsed
        // we can be sure before() was called because
        // it is ran before any tests run
        let user = context.user

        console.log('user in duplicateTests function: ', user)

        if (user) {
            done()
        } else {
            done(new Error('Dummy error'))
        }
    })
}

describe('users', () => {
    let context = {}

    before(() => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            context.user = await models.User.create({
                name: 'john',
            })
            resolve()
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
    }))

    describe('TEST THE BEFORE HOOK', () => {
        it('test 1', done => {
            console.log('user: ', context.user)

            if(context.user) {
                done()
            } else {
                done(new Error('Dummy error'))
            }
        })

        // context is passed by reference
        duplicateTests(context)
    })
})
```

Comment: when I do `user = await User.create()` outside the before hook, 'users' which is the message for root 'describe' never get's printed thus describe's callback function never get's executed. the second approach works with some small changes. I'll edit your answer to reflect those changes. thanks a lot. you saved me so much time.